# Unable to route to children components Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make use of multiple layout's for my angular application and have followed the below guide as per a previous post example but my child routing doesnt seem to work.

Guide I followed:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example

My app routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
path: '', component: BaseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {
      title: 'Base Layout', children: [
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } }
    }
]

 { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent, data: { title: 'Login' } },
  { path: 'logout', component: AuthLogoutComponent, data: { title: 'Logout' } },

  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];
```

how im trying to navigate to a child component in my navigation component

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
```

in my base component html:

```
<navigation></navigation>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my index.html i have

```
<html>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I can route to the non-children components fine, and it seems like the base component is working because my navigation appears on path '', but if i try navigate to any child it seems to throw the error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'
```

Comment: Your stackblitz and your question are not clear. Can you edit your question to make it understand better?

Comment: Kindly provide error message, you getting in console.Or you are navigating to pageNotFound component?

Comment: @varundhariyal, error message is at bottom of post, (if i remove the navigate to /404)   'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'

Comment: @ng-suhas, I want to have no layout for components like 'login' and a layout for components like 'dashboard'. My login component displays fine with no layout if i navigate to /login. If i navigate to '', my base layout shows my navigation (which is what i want) but then i try navigate to a child component '/dashboard' and it errors

Comment: Say me the steps to reproduce the error in stackblitz

Comment: For your `DashboardComponent` you have 2 paths. For the first one (`path: ""`) you should add  `pathMatch: 'full'` and `redirectTo: 'dashboard'`.

Comment: @riorudo, that did not fix

Comment: Try like `{ path: "", pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'' }` without the component and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use children route like this . Don't need to pass in data object

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardPageComponent },
    { path: 'product', component: ProductManagementComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
]}
```

Comment: Removing data object fixed it, but then made me realise it was a syntax fault. I did not  have a closing data object bracket before declaring my children.